# Magento ACL configuration

Tags: php, xml, security, magento, acl

I'm developing a small custom module for Magento that edits subscription information in a small form.  I have the data model all configured and I have built sample views with HTML forms.

However, when I try to post the forms the Magento system does not recognize the URLs due to the fact that the ACL portion of my xml files is not fully built out.

I have a viewAction, postAction and editAction inside my IndexController.  Does anyone have experience with this who can point me in the right direction?  I'm reviewing the documentation but it is confusing for an existing module.

Thanks in advance.

Kris

Comment: can you post your config.xml?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, please see my new thread at Magento Forms Not Posting in Custom Module", with full info.  -Kris

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a little broad for a single Stack Overflow action.  Here's a good starting point (self-link) that should allow you to describe the problem you're having better

http://alanstorm.com/magento_acl_authentication

Comment: After looking at this further, I am not sure the ACL is my issue.  All logged-in users can have access to my module.

Comment: Describe the urls you're trying to access in your post, and describe the routers section of your config. Someone should be able to help you with that information.

Comment: Thanks Alan, please see my new thread at "Magento Forms Not Posting in Custom Module".  -Kris

Comment: Please include relevant code in the body of your answer instead of only linking to an outside resource.